# Error using lighthouse inside of node app

Tags: node.js, lighthouse

Feels very simple...have installed lighthouse in my node app, but when I try to start the server I get the following error:

```
    /node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-core/gather/driver/execution-context.js:231
  static _cachedNativesPreamble = [
                                ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Node v14.16.0 & npm v7.8.0

That's literally it, if I just simply remove the import from my file it starts fine, so this happens just simply from importing the package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, must've been some weird copy/paste or file system issue. I took the project bootstrap from another one to start with.

To fix, I just created a new project fresh and it didn't have the issue anymore...very strange.